# problem with jQuery's .find().length in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer-8

I've Googled around, but I can't quite find a good solution to this problem. IE's developer tools haven't helped much on this front either.

This code for an xml document returned via ajax works in Safari, Chrome and Firefox:

```
$(data).find('Ticket').length;
```

The code returns, for example, the number 3.

The same code returns 0 in Internet Explorer 8. Why?

I have no doubt there's a simple explanation that involves either a) an IE quirk or b) a fault in my code that the other browsers forgive.

Comment: `find` expects a selector, is this a xml document? Are you using custom tags?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp --- there is part of browser support and The length property is supported in all major browsers.

Comment: @BoltClock and @Reiner Gerecke -- yes this is an xml document and Ticket is an element of the document. Sorry that wasn't clear. I edited the original question.

Comment: @mu is too short -- that also returns 0.

Answer (score 3):

find doesnt work in IE with custom tags (xml) unless you construct an activeX object

assuming the variable 'xml' is what is the xml returned from your request

```
    var data;

    if ($.browser.msie) 
    {
       data = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
       data.async = false;
       data.loadXML(xml);
    } 
    else 
    {
       data = xml;
    }
    //your code here
```

Comment: This was _very_ useful. This didn't work, but it led me to the answer. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Not sure why this didn't work for the OP. For me this worked perfectly and helped restore my sanity after hours of banging my head against the IE wall.

Answer (score 0):

Try out `$(data).find('ticket').size()`. This returns the same result as of `$(data).find('ticket').length`

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It returns the same result as .length: 0.

Comment: size() has been deprecated since jQuery 1.8
it is recommended to use length() instead

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Next answer.

Try

```
$('Ticket', data).length;
```

IE grabs xml differently than other browsers, firefox and chrome, alert($data) see if it is empty

Comment: Excellent idea. I tried it just now, but IE shows data isn't empty. It returns the correct xml via the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `find()` does in fact work in IE8, although perhaps it didn't back in February 2011.

In any case, I had exactly this problem today, and for me it was caused by the original ajax request: I had `dataType: 'html'` instead of `dataType: 'xml'`.

It's a silly mistake, but worth checking for.